# c3699 error while compiling class using System enum

Tags: c++, clr, destructor, virtual-functions

I am trying to compile a managed cpp(/clr) project. The code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class TestClass
{
public:
    //virtual ~TestClass() {}
    virtual void func() {}

    System::ConsoleColor color;
};

class Helper
{
public:
    static TestClass Help()
    {
        TestClass a;
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Helper::Help();
    return 0;
}
```

It fails to compile with following error

> error C3699: '&&': cannot use this indirection on type
>   'System::ConsoleColor'

If I add a trivial destructor (virtual or non-virtual) or I convert the function func() to non-virtual the compiler error is gone. Can someone explain the behavior. 
Also the compiler error happens on VS2015 and VS2017 but not on VS2013.

Comment: Works for me. Is this the complete code?

Comment: Which visual studio version are you using?